# How to remove injected link from drupal 7 project

Tags: google-analytics, drupal-7, sql-injection, google-ads-api, malware-detection

Our drupal 7 site infected with this link :

> https://click.clickanalytics208.com/s_code.js?cid=240&v=73a55f6de3dee2a751c3

Our google ads has been blocked by google due to this link.

We made:

1. All .js files immutable for same link;
2. Checked all code and database for same link.

But this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

- Check your database it maybe infected;
- Check contrib modules if you check customs;
- Check media it may be infected too;
- Try to disable all modules and go to standard theme (if it's production and you have opportunity put to maintenance mode).

Try to find not exactly this js, try to find executor of it.

Answer (score 0):

This specific scripts are added within php files, many times hidden within core files. Also, requesting Google to delist your site might help if you got rid of malicious embedded scripts.

Ping me if you need further help.

Comment: can you please help me to find scripts

Comment: Sure, I can help, how shall we contact each other ?

Comment: please contact me on hsmitkari@gmail.com or whatsapp me +919021027755, I need your help